# Convert Get-WmiObject win32_diskdrive to array in Powershell 4

Tags: arrays, powershell, get-wmiobject

How can I convert a Get-WmiObject command to an array and add it to a combobox?

This is the command line:

```
Get-WmiObject -Query "select DeviceID from win32_diskdrive" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty  DeviceID | ft -HideTableHeaders -AutoSize | Out-String
```

And this is the output result:

> \.\PHYSICALDRIVE0
>  \.\PHYSICALDRIVE1

I would like to write this like

> "\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0","\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1"

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The output from `Get-WmiObject ... |Select-Object ...` *is* already an array - `Format-Table -HideTableHeaders` simply outputs each object line-by-line.

If you want the string you describe in your question, avoid the `Format-*` and the `Out-String` cmdlets altogether:

```
PS C:\> $DiskDrives = Get-WmiObject -Query "SELECT DeviceID FROM Win32_DiskDrive" |Select-Object -ExpandProperty DeviceID
PS C:\> $DiskDrives -join ','
\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0,\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1
```

For double-quotes (`"`) around each element, I would go for the `-f` format operator:

```
PS C:\> $DiskDrives.ForEach({'"{0}"' -f $_}) -join ','
"\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE0","\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1"
```

Comment: That works very fine for me!! Thanks a lot for the help!